# Mock EF dbContext async methods using NSubstitute 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I got an error when trying to use [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) on my DbContext. So far I used the [EntityFramework.Testing](https://github.com/scott-xu/EntityFramework.Testing) package and the following code to set up my DbContext in the tests. It was quite simple, here's a sample from their site:

```
// Create some test data
var data = new List<Blog>
{
    new Blog{ Name = "BBB" },
    new Blog{ Name = "CCC" },
    new Blog{ Name = "AAA" }
};

// Create a DbSet substitute.
var set = Substitute.For<DbSet<Blog>, IQueryable<Blog>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<Blog>>()
                    .SetupData(data);

var context = Substitute.For<BloggingContext>();
context.Blogs.Returns(set);
```

This works nicely with version `3.1.0`, but throws the following exception if I upgrade NSubstitute to `4.0`.

> System.MissingMethodException
> Method not found: 'System.__Canon NSubstitute.Arg.Any()'.
> NSubstitute.NSubstituteDbSetExtensions.SetupData[TEntity](DbSet'1 dbSet, ICollection'1 data, Func'2 find)

I wonder if there's a good solution to mock EF contexts with async support or should I just stick to 3.1.0.

Comment: Might be worth asking [EntityFramework.Testing project](https://github.com/scott-xu/EntityFramework.Testing/issues) about NSubstitute 4.x support. 4.x changed the `Arg.` methods to support out/ref arguments, which may break compatibility with that library.

Comment: Don't mock Entity Framework, instead use "In-Memory" database for testing actual sql queries. Or do integration testing with actual database.

Comment: Yep. I hit the same exception. I rolled back to 3.1.0.